# How to set up compiler globally?

Tags: makeprg, errorformat

In my vimrc, I have a `compiler myCompiler`. When the editor starts up, everything is fine. When I switch to a new file, the `compiler` settings (`makeprg` and `errorformat`) revert to their defaults.

How can I set the `compiler` globally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:compiler!`.

From `:h :compiler`:

```
:comp[iler][!] {name}       Set options to work with compiler {name}.
                            Without the "!" options are set for the
                            current buffer.  With "!" global options are
                            set.
```